# Electrostatic potential...in electrodynamic regime in the expression $P=U.I$

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, potential, voltage, power

Let us consider a two terminal electrical component. It is typical to calculate the power it consumes by considering the voltage drop $U$ and the current passing through it $I$ and to say it absorbs a power $P=U.I$ (of course voltage and current should be oriented in the appropriate manner to say that it absorbs this power). I emphasize on the fact that this formula is also used when varying-in-time fields are considered (the instantaneous power reads $P(t)=U(t)I(t)$)

Now, from electromagnetism theory, we know (among other things) that:

$$\mathbf{E}=-\mathbf{\nabla} V - \partial_t \mathbf{A}$$
$$\mathbf{B}=-\mathbf{\nabla} \wedge \mathbf{A}$$
$$\mathbf{\nabla} \wedge \mathbf{B}=\mu_0 \mathbf{j} + \mu_0 \epsilon_0 \partial_t \mathbf{E}$$

In electrostatic regime, the relationship between voltage drop around two points $A$ and $B$, and electric field is simply:

$$U=\int_A^B \mathbf{E}.\mathbf{dl} $$

This is "consistant" with the general expression of the electric field I gave in term of potentials, assuming $\partial_t=0$

**Question1:**

*What happens in the varying regime ?* To what the $U$ in $P=U.I$ corresponds to ? Is it still the line integral of the electrical field ? If so, the voltage drop now depends on the precise path where the integration has been performed because we also integrate the quantity $\partial_t \mathbf{A}$. Then it is not really well defined because we don't need to specify "a path" when we talk about the voltage around a two terminal electrical component in varying regime.

Or maybe the answer is to take in general the "path independant" quantity:

$$U=\int_A^B (\mathbf{E}+\partial_t \mathbf{A}).\mathbf{dl} $$

**Question2:**

If the voltage drop is still defined as $U=\int_A^B \mathbf{E}.\mathbf{dl} $, how to make sense of the fact such definition depends on the exact path of integration ? Is there a way to make sense of it in the lumped-approximation regime, which means that we don't see spatial variation of electrical waves around the size of the electrical element we are considering ?

Comment: Sound like that you are talking a dipole-layer, not a dipole?

Comment: @ytlu I am talking about any electrical device that has two voltage "inputs". For instance capacitor, resistor, inductance etc. In french we call those "un dipole" but I am realizing that dipole in english probably only means the electrostatic dipole (i.e two opposite charge separated by a small distance). I am trying to find the appropriate word.

Comment: @ytlu The appropriate word is "two terminal electrical component" I think. I edited

Comment: @ytlu why do you assume a constant electric field in between ? A resistor can have a gradient of electric field in between.

Comment: I was misleading by your previous word "dipole". It set me into the senario of a dipole-layer -- two plates of opposite charges and a constant e-field in between.

Answer (score 0):

> **Question1:**
>
> *What happens in the varying regime ?* To what the $U$ in $P=U.I$ corresponds to ? Is it still the line integral of the electrical field ?

Most usually in AC circuits, voltage is drop of electrostatic potential, the line integral of electrostatic part of the field (the Coulomb field that depends only on charge distribution). The power $P=UI$ is then rate of work of electrostatic forces only (due to electric charge present because of battery or other energy source). This work turns up as other form of energy (for example, as *internal energy* ("heat") in a resistor or as a *magnetic energy* in ideal inductor).

We can try to change definition of $U$ to integral of total electric field along the current path, but then (if there is significant induced electric field present in the current path), the power $P=UI$ will have different meaning and value: rate of work of total electric field, which turns up always as *non-electromagnetic energy*. For example, rate of work of total electric field in a real inductor with ohmic losses turns up as internal energy in the inductor. With good conductivity, this can be much lower than rate of work of electrostatic forces.

"Voltage" both in physics and engineering is unfortunately an overloaded term and confusion is ubiquituous. Usually it is best to stick with the meaning

1. **voltage is drop of Coulomb potential** (thus integral of the Coulomb field, a quantity that depends only on endpoints, not path).

However, sometimes when only total field is known or of interest (working of a voltmeter) term "voltage" is used to mean

2. **voltage is integral of total electric field**, which then is not function of endpoints only, but depends on the path choice; and the chosen path is often assumed to be the path of electric current.

These two definitions are at odds with each other in situations with induced electric field, so one should use only one definition at a time or find another more descriptive name for quantity 2), e.g. "total electric electromotive force".

In AC circuit theory, where currents change in time, the first definition is actually the standard one and is much less confusing.

For example, potential drop on an *ideal* inductor (no material core, no ohmic losses) in the pre-chosen positive direction is known to be

$$
p.d. = L\frac{dI}{dt}.
$$
This is a unique value, self-inductance $L$ does not depend on choice of integration path in space, only on geometry of the ideal inductor. However, if we used the second definition of "voltage", on ideal inductor it would always be zero (because ideal inductor is made of ideal conductor for which total electric field vanishes inside). That would not be very useful as it would be inconsistent with the standard exposition of AC circuits.

> **Question2:**
>
> If the voltage drop is still defined as $U=\int_A^B \mathbf{E}.\mathbf{dl} $, how to make sense of the fact such definition depends on the exact path of integration ?

"Voltage drop" is a very confusing term for this, it is better to say just "voltage". The sense is made by the fact that some preferred path is implicitly assumed (path of electric current) so this "voltage" has unique value. This is just the definition 2) described above.

> Is there a way to make sense of it in the lumped-approximation regime, which means that we don't see spatial variation of electrical waves around the size of the electrical element we are considering ?

One could try to formulate everything in terms of definition 2) where only total field is used and the integration path is always the path the current takes. But it is not standard, see the problem with ideal inductor described above.

The solution is much simpler. In lumped element model of AC circuits, use the definition 1). The definition 2) is not needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. To be clear, the "Coulomb potential" you talk about corresponds to the term $V$ I used in my equations ? About your explanation for inductance I am not sure to understand how you can associate it with the Coulomb potential. Indeed isn't the ""voltage"" difference around an inductor caused by electromotive forces, thus by the *total* electric field integrated along the inductor (I guess on the path followed by its wire) ? If you could elaborate a bit on this last point it would be very helpfull for me !

Comment: It depends on how the potential $V$ is defined. If $V$ is defined as the Coulomb potential , then yes. There are other choices such as the one in Lorenz gauge where $V$ depends on past charge distribution at remote places, but we should ignore this approach for now.

Comment: Re inductor, p.d is result of non-trivial charge distribution on the inductor surface and other nearby bodies at the same time.

Comment: This charge appears due to "tendency" of the inductor to oppose the electromotive force by electrostatic forces. In ideal inductor, this tendency succeeds perfectly, as total electric field in the path of current is zero.

Comment: Hmmm ok. I roughly see what you mean but do you know a good source explaining all this ? I am now confused by the fact that indeed an ideal inductor doesn't have electric field inside of it so no electromotive force should be created. And at the same time the other equivalent explanation you provide with charge accumulation is unclear for me.

Comment: This is indeed a tricky subject, lots of sources get this wrong. You are perhaps confused by the slightly wrong definition of emf. Induced electromotive force  (emf) is simply integral of induced electric field $\mathbf E_i$ along the coils of the inductor. This field isn't zero inside the ideal inductor; if current is changing, it is very non-zero. We have nice formula for its net effect, $emf = -LdI/dt$.

Comment: However, in general this induced emf does not determine electric potential or difference of electric potential across the element. For that, we need to know the electrostatic field. The two kinds of fields have very different character in the whole space. But inside a good conductor, they partially cancel each other. The easiest case is perfect conductor, where they cancel completely. That's why in ideal inductor, from the fact emf is $-LdI/dt$ we can conclude that $p.d. = +LdI/dt$.

Comment: Yes but what confuses me is that a perfect conductor has $0$ total electric field inside. If your inductor is perfect the electric field within its material should be $0$. This is clearly in contradiction with how I understand the emf (when we express the integral of electric field by the mean of the magnetic field through Faraday law) inside of an inductor but this is what confuses me

Comment: In real inductor with ohmic losses the potential difference is not so simply related to emf, because some electric field is present inside the conductor. In the simplest case $p.d. = LdI/dt + RI$ where $R$ is ohmic resistance of the coiled path.

Comment: > Yes but what confuses me is that a perfect conductor has 0 total electric field inside. -- Indeed total field vanishes there. This is a limiting case that is hard to see in life, which is perhaps confusing. You need to realize that electric field is not needed in principle to have current. Current can just flow without electric field, just as Moon moves around the Earth without any pushing force - it is just inertia.

Comment: I agree but then if I try to find the emf inside the inductor I will have $emf=\int \mathbf{E}.\mathbf{dl}=0$. Thus even before relating the emf to the magnetic flux, I find $0$ emf. This is what confuses me and is contradictory with the rest.

Comment: > if I try to find the emf inside the inductor I will have emf=∫E.dl=0.  -- I can see your confusion. That integral over inductor path is indeed zero, which perhaps makes you think it is wrong as total EMF shouldn't be zero. However, that is not how total EMF for inductor is defined. It is rather defined as integral of *induced* electric field $\mathbf E_i$ over the coiled path of the inductor, from one terminal to another. This formula in *emf definition* can then be re-expressed using *total field* $\mathbf E$ and closed loop as integration path.

Comment: Integral of total electric field outside the inductor may not be zero. If it is (ideal conductor making the whole circuit), then indeed total induced EMF for that path will be zero no matter what.

Comment: "However, that is not how total EMF for inductor is defined. It is rather defined as integral of induced electric field $E_i$  over the coiled path of the inductor". If you want to take this definition for a quantity that you call "EMF", it would not be equal to $L dI/dt$ then. Because to get to this equation you need to use $\mathbf{\nabla} \wedge \mathbf{E} = -\partial_t \mathbf{B}$ and $\Phi=L I$. Where $\mathbf{E}$ is the **total** electric field (not the induced one). If you don't agree I would be interested to see how you derive $L dI/dt$ then.

Comment: The correct result for induced emf is with minus: $-LdI/dt$. I've added explanation of how this result is obtained back here https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/629955/emf-in-an-inductor-with-zero-resistivity-necesseraly-equal-to-0-is-it-impos/630058#630058

Comment: I agree with the minus I was a little sloppy. But then I don't see why you did not agree with me. Our definitions are strictly equivalent then. If the induced emf is the associated to the non conservative part of the field (which I did not know), our both statement are correct. So I am not sure to understand your objection.

Comment: Which statement of yours are you referring to?